# Onscreen keyboard (Onboard) doesn't work on login screen and makes desktop unusable after login

Tags: keyboard, login-screen, accessibility, onscreen-keyboard, onboard

I'm obliged to use the onscreen keyboard (i.e Onboard). I decided to update my PCs to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

However, I'm facing problems with the on-screen keyboard with all of them

- It's impossible to use the on-screen keyboard to log in - it appears on the login screen but it doesn't work
- Once I'm logged in, the keyboard does not stay floating at the bottom of the screen, but becomes stuck and pushes all my screen content up and my desktop becomes unusable.

I downloaded the keyboard that was available in 16.04. I also tried a fresh install on one of the machines. But the same issues persist.

I've tried:

- [Ubuntu 18.04 keyboard and mouse not working at login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135717/ubuntu-18-04-keyboard-and-mouse-not-working-at-login-screen)
  No change for me, still impossible to use the on screen keyboard for log in.
- [Keyboard not working after update to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033767/keyboard-not-working-after-update-to-18-04)
  same, no change

work PC:

- intel i5
- 16g ram
- nvidia 1050

wife's PC

- intel i3
- 8g ram
- nvidia gtx

If anybody has any idea how to get the keyboard to float over the content instead of getting fixed I would be very thankful.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Did you use google translate or just try in English? If you did not use translate you might want to, Most of this I am sorry makes no sense.

Comment: Many thanks but I think my problem is easy to understand, and it will be very handy to fix this issue for me.All the best.

Comment: My problem is: the on screen keyboard don't work for login.thanks

Comment: I have edited your question in an attempt to improve the explanation. My main confusion was that the word "onboard". I didn't know that was the package name of the virtual keyboard in Ubuntu. I tried to make that clear as well. Please delete the other answers as well since they don't answer the question, and include the details in your question instead.

Comment: I'd like to point out that I have faced similar issues myself as I have a touch screen on my Ubuntu machine. But I used to ignore them and never gave it much thought as I just switch to the laptop's keyboard. Having said that, this may be a bug and is worth filing a bug report in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/onboard) about it while trying to ask for a workaround here (if any). The lock screen issue is reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/onboard/+bug/1898199 it would be valuable to vote on it if you want it fixed. Project may be dead though.

Comment: How did you install `onboard`? From the Ubuntu repository 'universe', or from some other source? If you really used the version from 16.04, you can expect problems, because it was made for another version of Ubuntu. Which version is it? Please check with the command `apt-cache policy onboard` if you installed from a repository.

Answer (score 0):

`onboard` works for me in 20.04 LTS, at least when logged in. I have version 1.4.1-2ubuntu7, reported by

```
apt-cache policy onboard
```

You can modify the settings of `onboard` to make it float (instead of having it locked at the bottom of the screen) as shown in the following screenshot,

[image]

You have probably another language (than in the screenshot), but I think you can identify the options

- Click on the '123' button
- Click of the 'tools' button
- Select 'Window'
- Uncheck 'Dock to the screen edge'